# exponential performance cost on aggregated function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query

```
MATCH
(user:Users)-[watched:WATCH]->(movie1:MOVIES)<-[watches_too:WATCH]-(user2:Users)-[watches_other:WATCH]->(movie2:MOVIES)
where
 movie1.genre = "action" and
 movie1.title <> movie2.title and
 movie1.subgenre = movie2.subgenre and
 watched.date >= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01}) and
 watches_too.date >= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01})
RETURN
 user.id, movie2.title
LIMIT 100;
```

That query works, but it just return a movie2 title with almost no value, so I tried another aproach

```
MATCH
(user:Users)-[watched:WATCH]->(movie1:MOVIES)<-[watches_too:WATCH]-(user2:Users)-[watches_other:WATCH]->(movie2:MOVIES)
where
 movie1.genre = "action" and
 movie1.title <> movie2.title and
 movie1.subgenre = movie2.subgenre and
 watched.date >= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01}) and
 watches_too.date >= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01})
RETURN
 user.id, movie2.title, count(movie2) as ocurrence
 ORDER BY user.id, ocurrence DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

This way i tried to get the most watched movie by other users who also watched the same movie, but while the first query returns me in seconds results, the second took almost 2 hours to finish

Am I doing the aggregation wrong?

Also, while at it, the results went like 50 results for 1 user and 50 for another one, if I wanted to limit it to 2-3 movies per user?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Will running the query in a causal cluster help with the processing times?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too good at neo4j either, but I'll a try. Not really sure why the results are so large, but may be due to the second one having an `ORDER BY`

Here's what I came up with

```
MATCH
    (user:Users)-[watched:WATCH]->(movie1:MOVIES)
    WHERE
        movie1.genre = "action" and
        watched.date >= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01})
MATCH
    (user)-[watches_other:WATCH]->(movie2:MOVIES)
    WHERE
        movie1 <> movie2 and
        movie1.subgenre = movie2.subgenre and
        watches_too.date >= date({year: 2020, month: 06, day: 01})
WITH
    user.id AS id,
    COLLECT(movie2.title) as titles
RETURN
    id, titles
LIMIT 100;
```